# na] Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on **Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE and Spring Batch**. In this example, I am reading data from Oracle system and putting it into the Postgres system after applying some data filter.

Note - Spring Batch is able to read the data from `Oracle DB` but unable to write it into `PostgresDB`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1527/DB
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

postgres.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/admin?currentSchema=BATCH
postgres.datasource.username=postgres
postgres.datasource.password=postgres
postgres.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver


#By default, Spring runs all the job as soon as it has started its context.
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

# Chunk Size to save data
spring.chunk.size=200

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="oracleDS")
    @Primary
    public DataSource batchDataSource(){          
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                .build();          
    } 



    // All metadata tables are present here
    @Bean(name="postgresDS")
    public DataSource mysqlBatchDataSource(){          
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(env.getProperty("postgres.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("postgres.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .username(env.getProperty("postgres.datasource.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("postgres.datasource.password"))
                .build();          
    }
}
```

EmployeeBatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class EmployeeBatchConfig {
    private static final String SQL = "Get the Data";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="oracleDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="postgresDS")
    private DataSource dataSourcePostgresDB;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> EmployeeReader() throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setSql(SQL);

        reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> EmployeeWriter(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSourcePostgresDB);
        writer.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

        ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Employee> paramProvider = new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider (paramProvider);

        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO BATCH.EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID, FIRSTNAME) VALUES (:empId, :firstName)");
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH.EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID, FIRSTNAME) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:647) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:936) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:182) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.mastercard.customer.data.management.CustomerProfileStagingBatchApplication.run(CustomerProfileStagingBatchApplication.java:50) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mastercard.customer.data.management.CustomerProfileStagingBatchApplication.main(CustomerProfileStagingBatchApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10932) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11043) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$2(JdbcTemplate.java:950) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Note: When inserting the data into Postgres, but batch some how trying to load into Oracle only. Is there any @Bean qualifying issue ?

**@Solution:**

As suggested here: [Spring Batch - Unable to save the records into Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085861/spring-batch-unable-to-save-the-records-into-postgres-database/61087085?noredirect=1#comment108071901_61087085).

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO \"BATCH\".employee(rowid_object, status) VALUES (:rowid_object, :status)";
```

Comment: I really encourage you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. If someone takes time to help you in details (https://pasteboard.co/J2Q4AAR.png), it is not conform to SO code of conduct to remove the post (https://pasteboard.co/J2QWpff.png , https://pasteboard.co/J2QWxePK.png) without even saying thank you or accepting answers and then move on (since your issue is fixed) and post other questions under another identity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085861.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/J2R3t01.png. And feel free to downvote my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/61081771/5019386, I will still answer any question about Spring Batch in a professional way and according to SO code of conduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BATCH.EMPLOYEE` does not exist, that's why this error occurs.

You can use migration tools to run sql for create table and other modifications.
Some popular migration tools are `flyway` and `liquibase`.

Migration tools helps you to create and update your database.
It automatically run your defined sql files in a order your given.
When you need to update any table add another script file then it automatically run it.

Follow this step to configure :
https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/maven

[Database Migrations with Flyway Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you need to have the specific entity if you're initializing the statement as a bean for a specific table

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? I am looking to create target DB tables automatically, All efforts I am taking at making the object and then persist it .

Comment: Nope, I dont have JPA Entity for Employee, however I've created Employee model class because I am using SpringJDBC to save the data.

Answer (score -1):

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH.EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID, FIRSTNAME) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

According to this error, the table `BATCH.EMPLOYEE` does not exist. Make sure to create this table before running your job.

Comment: Right, my question is how can we create it automatically ?

Comment: Where is this table defined? Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization if you want Spring Boot to create it automatically.

Comment: Can we use the combination of Spring Jdbc (ItemReader) to read the data and JpaWriter to write the data to target system ?

Comment: I did not mention JPA, the link I shared is for all available options. If you want to use Flyway, here is the relevant section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup.

Comment: I am sorry, please confirm using Spring JDBC Can we create tables automatically ?

Comment: @PAA you can't auto generated Table using jdbc, it's better to use migration tools which can help to auto execute your sql

Comment: @AbinashGhosh - Thanks. Could you please share more info on migration tool ?