# Spring Batch - Unable to create metadata tables on Postgres and load actual data to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing `Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE + Spring Batch`. In this example, I am looking to read csv file, load the data into mysql and spring batch metadata tables into the Postgres database.

But This gives me error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringBatchMetadataInDiffSchemaApplication.main(SpringBatchMetadataInDiffSchemaApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "batch_job_instance" does not exist
  Position: 39
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:768) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:104) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.SpringBatchMetadataInDiffSchemaApplication.run(SpringBatchMetadataInDiffSchemaApplication.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "batch_job_instance" does not exist
  Position: 39
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:678) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

JobConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Qualifier("secondaryDS")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.csv"));

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id", "firstName", "lastName", "birthdate"});

        DefaultLineMapper<Customer> customerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        customerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        customerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CustomerFieldSetMapper());
        customerLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        reader.setLineMapper(customerLineMapper);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :birthdate)");
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer> chunk(1000)
                .reader(customerItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }   
}
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // For Test schema
    @Bean(name="secondaryDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource getSeconadaryBatchDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                .build();
    }

    // For "batchmetadata" tables
    @Bean(name="primaryDS")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.hello.datasource")
    public DataSource getPrimaryBatchDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(env.getProperty("spring.hello.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.hello.datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .username(env.getProperty("spring.hello.datasource.username"))
                .password(env.getProperty("spring.hello.datasource.password"))
                .build();
    }

    //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275448/multiple-data-source-and-schema-creation-in-spring-boot
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory( EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return builder
                .dataSource(getSeconadaryBatchDataSource())
                .packages("com.example.model")
                .persistenceUnit("default")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    /*@Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return builder
                .dataSource(getPrimaryBatchDataSource())
                .packages("com.example.model")
                .persistenceUnit("default")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }*/
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


# Postgres
spring.hello.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.hello.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/program?currentSchema=BATCH
spring.hello.datasource.username=postgres
spring.hello.datasource.password=admin

#spring.batch.table-prefix=batchmetadata.BATCH_
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Comment: just to get this straight, you want to have the batch job metadata in a separate postgres database, but the data in a mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Abinash for great help. I simply reverse Primary and Secondary. It worked.

```
# Datasource - Postgres - Primary
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/program?currentSchema=BATCH
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# MySQL- Secondary
spring.hello.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.hello.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.hello.datasource.username=root
spring.hello.datasource.password=root

#spring.batch.table-prefix=batchmetadata.BATCH_
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Also, using below worked.

```
writer.setSql("INSERT INTO \"BATCH\".customer VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :birthdate)");
```

Comment: That means BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE is your MySQL table searching in postgres db.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are creating table using quote like "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE".
Also check is schema is specified in `datasource.url` since you don't use schema name in query.

Comment: Spring Batch metadata tables should be created automatically for that we dont need to create it manually. I think issue is something different where Postgres DS is not acting as Primary, hence not creating metadata tables

Comment: @PAA In which file  `SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` query ?