# Spring Boot Spring Batch- Table or view doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to connect to the oracle database and have the url as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://....` instead of the localhost format. Not sure if I am able to connect or not.

I'm always getting the error:

> [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where
> JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
> exist.

My requirement it to just call a stored procedure in a schema and get the result. It looks like the `public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception` never gets executed.

Comment: The error says that the table does not exist in the db, hence unable to execute the query. Make sure you have the table created and exist and try the operation which you want to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [na\] Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081682/na-caused-by-java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-n)

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine ,@Arun sai --> spring.batch.initialize-schema=always , helped in solving the issue. Thank you